# UIDatePicker to show Month and year only

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [UIDatePicker select Month and Year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348247/uidatepicker-select-month-and-year)

Is there a way to have a UIDatePicker show month and year only? By default it shows month, day year. I dont want the day to show. I saw this but i dont think its what i need: [UIDatePicker select Month and Year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348247/uidatepicker-select-month-and-year).

Comment: That link is the same question that your asking.

Comment: That link I posted only selects the month and year and hard codes a day. when the datepicker appears the day will still show. I dont want that unless i'm missing something in the link which i probably am.

Answer (score 1):

There is no API to do this.  If you would like this feature to be available, please [file a report requesting it](https://bugreport.apple.com).

Thus, if you need this in your application, you'll have to recreate it yourself using a `UIPickerView`.

Answer (score -1):

Implement your own UIPickerView.