# How to represent month as corresponding numbers instead of month name in datepicker?

Tags: iphone

*How to   represent month as corresponding numbers instead of month name in datepicker*

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to customize a date picker. So if you want to solve your problem then use Custom PickerView. You can see here [UIDatePicker select Month and Year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348247/uidatepicker-select-month-and-year)