# iOS Date Picker with Day of Week Instead of Full Date

Tags: ios, uidatepicker

I would like to have an iOS date picker that allows the user to select a day of week and time. For example: Wednesday 12:00 PM. I do not need to display the month or the day of the month like below. Does anyone know how to just allow  the user to set only a day of the week and time? Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In default IOS Date picker, it is not posible. but if you still want this kind of picker then you need to use simple picker and add logic in it, i mean make it custom according to your requirement.

Comment: Thanks! I figured that might be what I had to do, just didn't know for sure.

Comment: Can i add the content in via XIB or do i need to program it in? just need three columns...

Comment: Hi, sorry for the shameless self-promotion but I created a library to do something similar - it shows the day of the week alongside the full date. Try it out here if you like: https://github.com/hughbe/Day-Date-Picker

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can customize `UIDatePicker` to show week days. I think you can use `UIPickerView` and create your own date picker.

See user [Igor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348247/uidatepicker-select-month-and-year/11150960#11150960) in this question to learn how to customize `UIPickerView`.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to pick day from a date picker then write only

```
[dateFormat setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];
```