# How to display only month and year in UIDatePicker?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uidatepicker

In my app i want to display expiration date its format is "M/yyyy" means 10/2014 using the help of default UIDatePicker Controller is it possible?

Comment: Similar, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348247/uidatepicker-select-month-and-year

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make your own custom class.As UIDatePicker not provide any api's to do that.You need to make custom picker and than fill with appropriate datasource.This [code](https://github.com/IgorFedorchuk/MonthYearDatePicker) will help you and does same.

Comment: How to hide previous year and month in this code like in UIDatePicker Controller to set minimum date and maximum date?

Comment: @bhavik yes you can.You need to do in `pickerView: (UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow: (NSInteger)row forComponent:` method.Check the month and year if it is less than current date month and year disable it or do not show it as required