# Show only Month and Year in Date Picker in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I need to allow user to enter their credit card expiration date. For this I have to show them date picker with only month and year options. I am using format="MM-yyyy", but no luck. Can anyone help me ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3348327/2520789):

> **No**, this cannot be done using the stock `UIDatePicker`

As such, you'll have to [make your own Xamarin Forms control](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/view/), and implement it on each platform. Meaning you'll have to use a default `UiPickerView` on iOS, and the equivalent on Android (and Windows Phone?).

Comment: Unfortunately my target is Windows phone only :(

Comment: If it is solely a Windows Phone, then why are you making a Xamarin Forms app?

Comment: Right now our target is only Windows phone but after our first release we should target Android and ios too

Comment: @Gans Wow we usually do the exact opposite. Any specific reason why you are doing it that way? Just curious.

Comment: Perhaps they're a company that has WP company phones? In any case, my answer still stands. You need to make a custom control, and create the renderers yourself.

Comment: @hvaughan3 - I actually do Windows Phone first because the development experience is soooo much better. Then with transferring to iOS and Android it is only UI issues to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

It would be a pain to customize each platform this. What I would recommend is to provide 2 regular text pickers, one with 01 - 12 or Jan - Dec whichever you prefer and the other with the next 20 years listed from today's year, so it dynamically updates as times goes on.

**Side Note:** 20 years seems to be the max most credit card providers would ever go, Amazon only goes to +20, but just letting you know there isn't a hard limit so there is a small possibility it could go further but very unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

You should customise a UIPickerView to use two components and populate its rows with month and year symbols retrieved from NSDateFormatter. Hope that works out for you!

Answer (score 0):

You only need to type this:

```
<DatePicker Format="MM/yyyy" />
```

^^