# Swift Month year pickerView with last 12 months

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview, uidatepicker

I am having a filter on a tableView, that has a 'From' and 'To' Months selection.

Month selection, I mean, when I select Month, the datePicker should show Month Year only. And the list should contain last 12 months from today.

I looked at the default UIDatePicker but realized that it is not possible to get only Month-Year. ([Reference answer from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348247/uidatepicker-select-month-and-year))

Further looking, I found [this link](https://github.com/bendodson/MonthYearPickerView-Swift) that has a custom month-year picker but it shows future 15 years. And, upon selection of any row, nothing happens.

Can someone help me customize it to show last 12 months from today and fetch the result upon selection?

Comment: If your picker is supposed to contain only 12 items use a standard picker and populate the items like "October 2017", "September 2017" etc.

Comment: but how do I get the last 12 months? Just need some logic to calculate that stuff please?

Comment: • Use `Calendar`. • Create `DateComponents(day: 1)` and `enumerateDates(startingAfter:matching:options:using:)` backwards until the number of items is reached. • Map the dates with `DateFormatter` to strings. • Populate the picker

Comment: sorry to ask, but do you have an example?

Comment: which month should be shown first? and next month should scroll to up or down?

Comment: current month (example: October 2017) to be shown first. and show previous 12 months from current month. (example October 2017, Sep '17, Aug '17, .... Nov '16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple example to get the last 12 months

```
var last12Months = [Date]()
let firstDayComponent = DateComponents(day: 1)
Calendar.current.enumerateDates(startingAfter: Date(), 
                 matching: firstDayComponent, 
                 matchingPolicy: .nextTime, 
                 direction: .backward, 
                 using: { (date, idx, stop) in
    if let date = date {last12Months.append(date) }
    if last12Months.count == 12 { stop = true }
})

print(last12Months)
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "MMMM yyyy"
print(last12Months.map({formatter.string(from: $0)}))
```

Comment: thanks vadian... am checking this... will have to get this in my pickerView... and upon selection, I need the value of selected row

Comment: Populating a picker view is pretty straightforward.

Comment: the above code gives me months in 1995. I don't see a reason why :( can you check if you are around please?

Comment: The problem occurs only on 1st October - every year!

Comment: @LohithKorupolu I regard this as a bug and reported it to Apple.

Comment: thank you very much for your quick response. I could not figure it out what was going wrong, so had to come to you. Is there a way where I can see the bug/details?

Comment: @LohithKorupolu I don't think so. This is Objective-C API which is private. Apple will send me a notification what they did but not in detail.